# Print current logged in user without link

Tags: 7

I'd like to print out the name of the user that is currently logged in, but not have it be a link.

Currently I have:

```
<?php print l($user_name, 'user/' . $user->uid);?>
```

But this prints out a link to their user profile. Any way to make their name just text and not a link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`l()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/l/7) is the function that creates a link, so...

```
<?php print $user_name; ?>
```